# How big or small is a reference frame in Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

What exactly is a [frame of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference)? Does it have an objective existence and if so what is it?

What's the size of a reference frame? Is a reference frame the same size for a stationary frame of reference and one that's accelerating?

What's the smallest frame of reference? Does a photon or electron have a reference frame or does this just apply to classical objects?

Comment: Have a look at the top few Q./As in [this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=inertial+frame+is%3Aquestion). I'm not sure that there is an exact duplicate of your question, but I think reading the answers to the first few questions will also answer yours.

Comment: I read those before I posted and there wasn't any answer to my questions. I've read an inertial frame of reference is small, but how small? What's the exact size of the smallest frame of reference. What's the limit on how big this reference frame can get? I guess I'm looking for hard numbers. Does it have an objective existence or is a reference frame something abstract that depends on the event occurring? Does that mean space-time is just an abstract in relation to the event occurring?

Answer (score 2):

A frame of reference is just a momentary choice for the direction of time (and therefore, for what constitutes space, as space is orthogonal to time).  A choice of reference frame is not conceptually different from choosing a direction for "up" on a map.  Once you have chosen "up" at some point, the notions of left and right become clear.

All of us are going through spacetime, and the "direction" we travel through spacetime defines how we split things up into space and time.  A reference frame is merely a choice of time direction against which to make measurements.  It no more "exists" than it would make sense to say a compass rose exists on a map.  You can write it down or describe it, but it is not a thing in and of itself.

A reference frame has no size.  Strictly speaking, a choice of frame at a point says nothing about what frames might be used at other nearby points.

Any timelike object can be said to have an instantaneous reference frame.  Photons are different in that their trajectories do not split up spacetime into space and time.

---

What is spacetime?  Again, I return to the analogy of a map.  On a map, you have many different locations and features.  Each point on a map represents a location.  Spacetime is a map for the whole history of the universe, in which a point in spacetime represents not just a location, but a particular location at a particular time.

On a map, you can freely choose which direction is "up" (and therefore what is left or right).  There are many choices of map coordinates that you might make, depending on what is convenient, but these choices do not change or alter the arrangements of locations in any substantive way:  all the locations are the same, you're just describing them with numbers differently.

For spacetime, a choice of reference frame is a choice for the direction of time and the directions of space as a result.  This means that points in spacetime can be described with different combinations of space and time coordinates, each set of coordinates unique to a particular reference frame--to a particular choice of directions--but these choices do not in any way move events around in spacetime.  The coordinates are different merely because one chooses the directions used to measure those coordinates differently.

So, what is spacetime?  A model for how events in the universe fit together in a way that can be described with coordinates for space and time.

Does it have an objective existence?  I answered the previous question trying to emphasize that reference frames are all math, in the sense that you cannot reach out and touch one.  You can't reach out and touch spacetime either, but the model has been successful--especially in how objects influence spacetime and therefore influence the paths of other objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what's spacetime? Does spacetime have an objective existence and if so what is it? As I understand it, two observers can experience the same event differently depending on their frame of reference. If this is the case, what's spacetime and how can it be any more "real" than a conceptual reference frame?

Comment: "As I understand it, two observers can experience the same event differently depending on their frame of reference." You'll have to be more specific here; I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I've added a section on spacetime, however.

Comment: What I'm saying is, a stationary observer might see lightning strike a train in the front and the back of the train simultaneously but an observer sitting on the train might see the lighting strike the front of the train first from their frame of reference and both the stationary observer and the observer riding on the train would be correct. Also, doesn't this mean what we call spacetime is a 4th dimension of space and we look at the evolution of events in the 3rd dimension externally from this 4th dimension of space?

Comment: Also, I saw this from Einsteins book Relativity. "Since there exist in this four dimensional structure [space-time] no longer any sections which represent "now" objectively, the concepts of happening and becoming are indeed not completely suspended, but yet complicated. It appears therefore more natural to think of physical reality as a four dimensional existence, instead of, as hitherto, the evolution of a three dimensional existence." So we would view 3 dimensional existence externally from the 4th dimension.

Comment: Re: train. Yes, relativity tells us that's purely a geometric phenomenon. Imagine two people standing in line with two fenceposts.  One person faces the line of fenceposts and perceives that one post is closer in the direction he's facing than the other.  The other person faces perpendicular to the posts and perceives that both posts are equally far ahead of him. That's trivial, of course: you know that the two people, though facing different directions, are perceiving the same physical system. Think of the observers in your question as merely facing different directions through spacetime.

Comment: Thanks again and I just blew my own mind a little. I Googled to see if anyone thought the 4th dimension of time was really space and found a few Scientist saying the same thing. It would seem to me that the 4th dimension of space allows us to see the evolution of events in the 3rd dimension. Just like a hypothetical 4th dimensional being would need an external 5th dimension in order to view the evolution of events in the 4th dimension. So there isn't any objective measure of time unless there's like 5 or 10 dimensions of space and one external dimension of time.